# Multiprocessing program (producer-consumer) exits without printing anything Python 3

Tags: python, parallel-processing, process, multiprocessing

I'm trying to create shared Queue from which tasks are to be taken for execution and pushed for execution. However, program doesn't print anything and exits with code 0.

I'm using python 3.6 and tried everything I found on internet but it is not working. Maybe I'm missing something or doing something wrong. Please point me to the right direction.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time


def produce(i, rate, taskQue):
    print("+++ Producer:%s +++" % i)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    for r in range(rate):
        taskQue.put(0)
    time.sleep(1)


def consume(i, rate, taskQue):
    print("--- Consumer:%s ---" % i)
    for r in range(rate):
        while taskQue.empty():
            print("| Consumer:%s ..." % i)
            time.sleep(0.5)
        time.sleep(0.01)
        taskQue.get()
    time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = mp.Manager()
    taskQue = manager.Queue()

    producerDetails = [[1, 5, taskQue], [2, 7, taskQue], [3, 2, taskQue], [4, 3, taskQue]]
    producerPool = mp.Pool(processes=5)
    produced = producerPool.apply_async(produce, producerDetails)

    consumerDetails = [[1, 5, taskQue], [2, 5, taskQue], [3, 3, taskQue], [4, 5, taskQue]]
    consumerPool = mp.Pool(processes=5)
    consumed = consumerPool.apply_async(consume, consumerDetails)

    producerPool.close()
    producerPool.join()
    consumerPool.close()
    consumerPool.join()
```

Comment: Maybe you should not close the pools before they are done?

Comment: I've read in the documentation that after closing pool it will not accept more work. It doesn't concern with pool actually stop processing and killing all processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what I did wrong. The problem is that pool worker is not able to take parameters that are specified in `produce()` and `consume()`. Each takes three parameters. However, `producerDetails` and `consumerDetails` lists are passed directly to `Pool.apply_async()` are mapped list as one and not three separate parameters from sub-list.

For this purpose there is `Pool.starmap()` and `Pool.starmap_async()` functions that will accept the current list and map parameters correctly.

In case someone doesn't understand what I meant above, Here's working code in Python 3.6

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time


def produce(i, rate, taskQue):
    for r in range(rate):
        print("+++ Producer:%s +++" % i)
        time.sleep(i * 0.01)
        taskQue.put(0)
    time.sleep(1)


def consume(i, rate, taskQue):
    for r in range(rate):
        while taskQue.empty():
            print("| Consumer:%s ..." % i)
            time.sleep(0.5)
        print("--- Consumer:%s ---" % i)
        time.sleep(i*0.01)
        taskQue.get()
    time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = mp.Manager()
    taskQue = manager.Queue()

    producerDetails = [[1, 5, taskQue], [2, 7, taskQue], [3, 2, taskQue], [4, 3, taskQue]]*50     
    producerPool = mp.Pool(processes=20)

    consumerDetails = [[1, 5, taskQue], [2, 5, taskQue], [3, 3, taskQue], [4, 5, taskQue]]*50
    consumerPool = mp.Pool(processes=20)

    produced = producerPool.starmap_async(produce, producerDetails)
    consumed = consumerPool.starmap_async(consume, consumerDetails)

    producerPool.close()
    producerPool.join()
    consumerPool.close()
    consumerPool.join()
```